# Thread-safe buffer that propagates the latest data

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have a data source which creates (produces) a `PointF` every 15 to 20 milliseconds.
I need to store (consume) such points every 10ms. My approach is to use a 3 points wide buffer and pointers to achieve a lock-free access:

```
protected class PosBuffer
{
    PointF[] m_Buffer = new PointF[3];
    volatile int m_ReadPointer = 0;
    volatile int m_WritePointer = 1;
    internal PosBuffer()
    {
        m_Buffer[0] = new PointF(0, 0);
        m_Buffer[1] = new PointF(0, 0);
        m_Buffer[2] = new PointF(0, 0);
    }

    internal void Write(PointF point)
    {
        m_Buffer[m_WritePointer] = point;
        m_ReadPointer++;
        if (m_ReadPointer == 3) m_ReadPointer = 0;
        m_WritePointer++;
        if (m_WritePointer == 3) m_WritePointer = 0;
    }

    internal PointF Read()
    {
        return m_Buffer[m_ReadPointer];
    }
}
```

My idea is that

- as soon as new data arrives it will be stored 'above' the old data. Then the read pointer is set to this position and then the write pointer is incremented.
- in case now new data has been produced the consumer thread reads the old data again.
- This construction allows different or inconstant read and write rates.

My questions are:

- would this approach work?
- Do I need locks/monitors/critical sections...
- Would I need to disable optimization?
- Are there known better solutions?

Comment: How about ```ConcurrentQueue``` or ```ConcurrentStack```

Comment: An important feature of my approach I might not make clear: The reader/consumer thread needs to read only the latest data. In case there's no new data it re-reads the old data. In a queue all data is consumed which is not what I need.

Comment: You don't seem to have any requirements that can't be satisfied by a single volatile reference.

Comment: So your implementation is equivalent to a graphics triple buffer? If you only have one writer thread, you should only need one pointer. You can drop the `volatile` and instead use a memory barrier to ensure the new `m_Buffer` element is flushed to ram before updating the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var ct = cts.Token;
    var pb = new PosBuffer();
    var tw = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;
            pb.Write(new PointF());
        }
    });

    var tr = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;
            pb.Read();
        }
    });
    
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
    
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Fairly quickly it throws `IndexOutOfRangeException`. You're letting the value of the "pointers" (bad name by the way) be `3` before dropping back to `zero` and in the time it takes to change it down the read operation throws.

The problem goes away if you increment like this:

```
m_ReadPointer = (m_ReadPointer == m_Buffer.Length - 1) ? 0 : m_ReadPointer + 1;
m_WritePointer = (m_WritePointer == m_Buffer.Length - 1) ? 0 : m_WritePointer + 1;
```

Now, if you have multiple writers then you're definitely going to need locking.

Comment: Indeed this IndexOutOfRange I oversaw. Fortunatelly I only have one producer and one consumer thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a [`BroadcastBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.broadcastblock-1) from the [TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) library:

> Provides a buffer for storing at most one element at time, overwriting each message with the next as it arrives.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

// Initialize
BroadcastBlock<PointF> block = new(x => x);

// Write the latest value
block.Post(new PointF(0, 0));

// Fetch the latest value
PointF point = await block.ReceiveAsync();
```

Another idea is to use a [`BehaviorSubject<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211949(v=vs.103)) from the [Rx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/).

> Represents a value that changes over time.

```
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

// Initialize
BehaviorSubject<PointF> subject = new(new PointF(0, 0));

// Write the latest value
subject.OnNext(new PointF(0, 0));

// Get the latest value
PointF point = subject.Value;
```

Both classes (`BroadcastBlock<T>` and `BehaviorSubject<T>`) are thread-safe.

Comment: These solutions are tempting! Why haven't I yet heared from those?

Comment: @M.Enke none of these libraries is very popular for different reasons. The TPL Dataflow is a bit aged, it was designed to support a wide range of scenarios that resulted in too complex interfaces and interactions between the components, which makes it a pain to extend it. The Rx is based on much cleaner interfaces, but nevertheless it has a steep learning curve and it's currently a semi-abandoned project. Both are still usable though.

Answer (score 0):

For your case of single value, I would suggest [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-7.0) assuming
you need thread safe reads and writes with multiple threads.

```
protected class PosBuffer
{
  private PointF m_Buffer;
  private ReaderWriterLockSlim m_Lock = new();

  internal void Write(PointF point)
  {
    m_Lock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        m_Buffer = point;
    }
    finally
    {
        m_Lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }

  internal PointF Read()
  {
    m_Lock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        return m_Buffer;
    }
    finally
    {
        m_Lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is just the locks I do not want since for what reason ever sometimes they take too much time especially if there's a 'try'. At least thtis is my expreience.

Comment: @M.Enke: its hard in `.net`, there is another technique called `compare-and-swap` where you loop and use `Interlocked.CompareExchange`. However, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is also a spin lock. Any other higher abstractions you are going to use like `TPL Dataflow` or even the new `Channels` they are going to use locks.